# I want to get data if records are not present in specific month

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I wrote a sql query to get all records happen in specific month

```
select month(loggingdate),Count(id) from communicationlogs 
where clientid=20154 and month(loggingdate) in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
group by month(loggingdate)

7   65
8   5
```

here records are present in 7th and 8th month. I want to get 0 value for other month numbers like-

```
1   0
2   0
3   0
4   0
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a standard problem where a calendar table comes in handy.  A calendar table, as the name implies, is a table which just stores a sequence of dates.  In your particular case, we only need the digits corresponding to the 12 months.  Begin the query with the calendar table and then left join to your aggregation query as a subquery.

Note the use of `COALESCE` below.  If a given month appears nowhere in your original query, then its count would show up as `NULL` in the join, in which case we report zero for that month.

```
WITH calendar_month AS (
    SELECT 1 AS month 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT month +1 
    FROM
    calendar_month
    WHERE month +1 <= 12
)

SELECT
    t1.month,
    COALESCE(t2.cnt, 0) AS cnt
FROM calendar_month t1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT
        MONTH(loggingdate) as month,
        COUNT(id) AS cnt
        FROM communicationlogs 
        WHERE
            clientid = 20154 AND
            MONTH(loggingdate) IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
        GROUP BY MONTH(loggingdate)
) t2
    ON t1.month = t2.month
```

Comment: any simple query please ?

Comment: If you're using a CTE why not making it a recursive one to generate the number from 1 to 12 instead of 12 SELECT statements? `SELECT 1 as NextRunDate
  UNION ALL
   SELECT 
    NextRunDate +1
  FROM    
   CTE
  WHERE 
   NextRunDate + 1 <=12`

Comment: Unfortunately this is just about as simple as it gets.  If you don't want to use a calendar table then you can change your business process such that always write a zero record for each month to the table.  This would guarantee that each month would always appear.

Comment: @Cosmin That is way past my paygrade :-)  ... but feel free to edit my question if you want.

Comment: Is it possible without CTE?

Comment: @johncena Yes, you can create a temporary or permanent table with the same data.  I only gave the CTE because it would allow you literally cut and paste my code, and it leaves the answer feeling more complete.

Comment: @johncena Does the CTE scare you? You can treat it like a temporary table

Comment: @cosmin i wanted a short solution because i already using CTE in my proc